# What's the security risk of setting too large MaxJsonDeserializerMembers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to set some aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers value to appsettings, but there is warning without explanation of what is the risk of setting "too large". 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh975440(v=vs.120)
So what are the risks? And how much "too large" is?

Comment: Denial of service, mostly. If a malicious application is allowed to stream 2 GB of data into yours for further parsing (which takes up proportionally more memory), it may take a long time for processing to complete, if at all, and existing requests could be aborted when the whole site runs out of memory. There is no one obvious value that's "too large" as that would depend on your machine's hardware and the actual legitimate load on your site. There should be no risk of buffer overflow, as the ASP.NET JSON parser uses pure managed code.